# Symfony 2.8 : inject mocked repository in a test controller

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.8

I try to create a test for a custom controller. In this one, this is what is executed:

**Code**

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
                ->findAllOrderedByName();
```

In the test controller, this is what I am doing:

```
$entityManager = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            ->setMethods(['getRepository', 'clear'])
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $entityManager
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->with('MyBundle:User')
            ->will($this->returnValue($userRepositoryMock));


        // Set the client
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->getContainer()->set('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', $entityManager);
```

**Problem**

But at the end the test fails because my mock seems to no be used:

> tests\MyBundle\Controller\ListingControllerTest::testAllAction
>   Expectation failed for method name is equal to string:getRepository
>   when invoked 1 time(s).
>   Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

Following remarks on comments, I created a service:

```
services:
    my.user.repository:
        class:   MyBundle\Entity\UserRepository
        factory: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', getRepository]
        arguments:
          - MyBundle\Entity\User
```

So now, I "just" have to mock the repo:

```
$userRepositoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder('MyBundle\Entity\UserRepository')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['findAllOrderedByName'])
            ->getMock();

        $userRepositoryMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('findAllOrderedByName')
            ->will($this->returnValue($arrayOfUsers));
```

and inject it into the container:

```
$client->getContainer()->set('my.user.repository', $userRepositoryMock);
```

But I still have the same issue

Comment: try replacing the service name `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` with simple `doctrine`

Comment: I have the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't inject container/entity manager in the testing class, instead inject doctrine repositories [directly](https://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/). Also, don't create kernel in your test, tests should run fast.

UPDATE 1:
The testing service should require repository in constructor. So in your test you are able to replace it with mock.
`$client = static::createClient()` is for testing controllers against the real database with fixtures (functional test). Don't use it for testing services with mocked dependencies (unit test).

UPDATE 2: Example of unit test:

```
class UserServiceTest extends UnitTestCase
{
    public function test_that_findAllWrapper_calls_findAllOrderedByName()
    {

        //GIVEN
        $arrayOfUsers = [$user1, $user2];

        $userRepo = $this->getMockBuilder('AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $userRepo
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('findAllOrderedByName')->willReturn($arrayOfUsers);


        $userService = new UserService($userRepo);

        //WHEN
        $result = $userService->findAllWrapper();

        //THEN
        $this->assertEquals($arrayOfUsers, $result);
    }
}

class UserService {
    private $userRepo;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->userRepo = $repo;
    }

    public function findAllWrapper()
    {
        return $this->userRepo->findAllOrderedByName();
    }
}
```

Comment: @enrico69 I added some explanation, you are mixing unit and functional testing

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, I didn't realize I was mixing unit and functionnal tests as I was testing a controller. However, could you give me and example for this point: "The testing service should require repository in constructor. So in your test you are able to replace it with mock"

Comment: I think the point is that you should not be trying to unit test controller actions at all.   Take the functionality that you are trying to test and move it into it's own service(s).  Then test the service.  Your controller code should end up being very slim.

Comment: @cerad I am not unit testing but functionnal testing a controller, and the controller is already very slim.

Comment: @enrico69 - Have fun.  Pretty much by definition you won't be mocking anything for functional testing.  If you want to test your UserRepository::findAllOrderedByName method then you should unit test it without using the container or any of that stuff.  But that of course it up to you.

Comment: Thanks you for your time for both of you